# Safari renders padding different

Tags: html, css, safari

The Nav looks fine in Chrome and Firefox, but Safari breaks into a new line.

Safari:

[image]

Chrome:

[image]

CODE PEN: http://codepen.io/patrickhofer/pen/vKEbao

The nav has this CSS:

```
nav {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
nav ul li  {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    height: 100%;
}
nav ul li h1  {
    font-size: 40.5px;
    font-weight: 600;
    height: 100%;
}
/* PADDING FOR NAV */
.navp {
    padding-right: 44.3px;
    height: 100%;
}

#reflect h1:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}


#reflect {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-reflect: below -3px -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%);
}


#reflect:before {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #FFFFFF, #FFFFFF 30%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 65%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)) repeat scroll 0 0 padding-box, -moz-element(#reflect) no-repeat scroll 0 -127px content-box rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  content: "";
  height: 140px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 277px;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
  transform: scaleY(-1);
  width: 360px;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <nav>
        <ul>
            <li id="reflect" class="navp txtRot"><h1>HOME</h1></li>
            <li id="reflect" class="navp txtOrange"><h1>ANGEBOT</h1></li>
            <li id="reflect" class="navp txtGelb"><h1>TEAM</h1></li>
            <li id="reflect" class="navp txtGruen"><h1>UMWELT</h1></li>
            <li id="reflect" class="txtBlau"><h1>KONTAKT</h1></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

I'm using this as simple CSS reset:

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like Safari rounds up the font-size to a whole number. If the sizing is important, you could change the font-size down to 40px and do a scale transform on the parent element.